# Grammatical structure of this sentence

Tags: sentence-structure, grammar-identification

> Um besser verstehen zu können, welche Aspekte der Kybernetik die ostdeutschen Wissenschaftler übernommen haben, aber auch um zu zeigen, in wie weit die Kybernetik bereits zu Beginn ideologisch geprägt war, ist es unvermeidlich, einen knappen Abriß ihrer Entstehungsgeschichte zu geben. " The deciding factor in this new step was the war ", hatte es prägnant der Gründervater der Kybernetik in den Vereinigten Staaten, der Mathematiker Norbert Wiener, **in seinem der neuen Theorie den Namen gebenden emblematischen Buch** *Cybernetics* auf den Punkt gebracht. Wiener bezog sich mit dieser bezeichnenden Feststellung auf seine 1940/41 durchgeführten Forschungen über die Verbesserung von Flugabwehrsystemen, mit denen er bereits vor dem Eintritt der Amerikaner in den Krieg begonnen hatte.
> <sub>*Source: http://www.trend.infopartisan.net/trd0109/t050109.html*</sub>

Could somebody help me with that bolded part? I think some grammatical elements are put in the middle of "in seinem ... Buch," but have no idea about that. My hunch is that the author meant that Wiener took the name of his theory Cybernetics as the title of the book as well. But I don't understand how this idea could be grammatically expressed between "seinem" and "Buch."

Comment: If you want to have texts analyzed, please always quote the original sentence with some additional context. I fond the website with that sentence and added more context than you postet.

Comment: While in the general case true, you are doing this question here a dis-service @HubertSchölnast Your edit is counter-productive to the understanding and the OP made an effort to work out and highlight the parts he is concerned about, cutting away the parts he is fine with. I vote to revert the unwarranted edit to the detriment of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is a good one.

Let's look at it element by element.
You deduce correctly, that the main object is **in seinem Buch**.

Now we add an adjective to 'Buch': *in seinem **emblematischen** Buch*

Now we add an insert **der neuen Theorie den Namen gebenden** (=giving the new theory a name) a participle group (Partizipialgruppe oder -Einschub) as a further description or explanation for the book. We could rephrase this with another sentence, e.g.

> Wiener... hatte es in seinem emblematischen Buch Cybernitics auf den Punkt gebracht und mit dem Titel der neuen Theorie einen Namen gegeben. (oder auch: ...mit dessen Titel...)

or more often as a subjunctive clause (here relative clause):

> Wiener... hatte es in seinem emblematischen Buch Cybernetics, das der neuen Theorie den Namen gab, auf den Punkt gebracht

Comment: Wow.. I finally got it. Thank you sooooooo much!